# Cannot use nor find class AuthCredentials

Tags: java, solr, solrj

Securing Solr with HTTP basic authentication works fine.

But trying to find this class is impossible:

> With SOLR-4470 this has changed a little, because a class AuthCredentials encapsulating the abstract concept of
>   credentials was introduced [(1)](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity#Providing_credentials_in_requests_from_your_own_client)

Providing the credentials for a request in a Java application using the classes `AuthCredentials` and `HttpClientUtil` is impossible as it seems `AuthCredentials` does not exist (at least [where the Solr Wiki links to](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AuthCredentials)) and the documentation does not list `HttpClientUtil.setAuthCredentials` which the [Wiki mentions](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity#Providing_credentials_in_requests_from_your_own_client) to be present. Solrj does not contain them. What did I miss? Using Solr 4.5.1 and Solrj 4.6.0